# QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message. The request failed with an empty response

Tags: wordpress, quickbooks

I am not a programmer and unfortunately the programmers that have tried to help me could not. I connected my Woocommerce site successfully to Quickbooks using Webconnector initially. An unknown event caused us to receive this error, and since then webconnector has not been able to connect. I uninstalled then reinstalled the plugin and webconnector, and deleted all the old files on the database. Then it seemed to work for a split second, then produced the same error. The programmer suggested that it is because my main website is http not https. The shopping cart and admin pages are set to https.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I apologize if I am providing an excess of information, but here is the log information.

20140424.07:06:53 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20140424.07:06:53 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20140424.07:06:53 UTC   :  : ~SingleInstanceHandler() - usingInstanceChannel = false. Returning without any Registry key delete or unmarshalling.
20140424.07:07:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : updateWS() for application = 'WooCommerce QuickBooks Connector' has STARTED
20140424.07:07:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
20140424.07:07:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
20140424.07:07:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************
20140424.07:07:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20140424.07:07:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: WooCommerce QuickBooks Connector
20140424.07:07:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): WooCommerce QuickBooks Connector
20140424.07:07:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: https://www.farmacisthealing.com/?qbconnector=4Ty8Curko000
20140424.07:07:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20140424.07:07:03 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Actual error received from web service for serverVersion call: . For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-serverVersion.
20140424.07:07:03 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : This application does not contain support for serverVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20140424.07:07:03 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:
20140424.07:07:04 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Actual error received from web service for clientVersion call: . For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-clientVersion.
20140424.07:07:04 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application does not contain support for clientVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20140424.07:07:04 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'WooCommerce QuickBooks Connector', username = 'FHLLCQB'
20140424.07:07:04 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:
20140424.07:07:05 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
The request failed with an empty response.
More info:
StackTrace =    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.authenticate(String UserName, String Password)
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)
Source = System.Web.Services

Answer (score 0):

Your programmer already answered your question:

> The programmer suggested that it is because my main website is http not https.

If you visit the URL:

- https://www.farmacisthealing.com/?qbconnector=4Ty8Curko000

You'll see you get bounced to a non-HTTPS URL immediately. That shouldn't be happening. Either  your website is configured wrong and redirecting you, or your web host/web server is configured wrong and redirecting you.

Comment: Thank you for re-confirming this. Now solving that problem is where we are struggling at the moment. I contacted my hosting provider and we tried deactivating all plugins and forcing the redirect with an .htaccess file. But when that didn't work, even using a code that should force all visits to our website to https didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: If I had to guess, I would guess your actual website PHP scripts are forwarding things to a non-HTTPS site, because if you visit one of the wp-content/ URLs, it *doesn't* forward you. Only the actual PHP pages forward you away from HTTPS. Have you asked your developer why the PHP scripts are forwarding you away from HTTPS?

Comment: I will ask! Thank you!